# how to tune wave to obtain a specific harmonic seriers

Tags: harmonics, square

I wanted to know what is the relationship between a square wave and its harmonics, in other words can i change a square wave features (frequency, duty cycle etc) to obtained a desired fundamental frequency (and its corresponding harmonics)?
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Search in YouTube ' Fourier transform 3 blue 1 brown '.  Also see popular video related to fourier series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature of a square wave that you change to obtain a desired fundamental frequency, is the frequency.

At a duty cycle of 50%, there are no even (2n) harmonics. At a duty cycle of 33.3%, there are no 3n harmonics, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Examine how sin(duty_cycle / period) /(duty_cycle / period) affects the energy.

Also examine how the # of period (the correlation time) affects the  width of each spectral region; they widen greatly, no longer thin lines of energy.